# How to gather processed information from nodes SLURM/PBS

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, pbs, slurm

I am new to Parallel computing, I cannot understand the use of PBS systems. I have successfully install SLURM and set up processing nodes. But cannot get the idea how I can distribute a task between multiple nodes.

There are a lot of simple examples, but they just run simple "Hello World" programs and that's all.

Consider the following example, I've found on the internet.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH --time=0-00:15:00     # 30 minutes
#SBATCH --job-name="just_a_test"

module load python
python --version
```

Simple script that run gets the Python version.

When I run it using `sbatch python.slurm`, the result is saved only on the first node even if I set the number to 4. But `srun -N4 /bin/hostname` works fine on the other hand.

But this is not the main question.

I cannot understand what I have to write my parallel algorithm.

Any example of parallel algorithm like array sorting, matrix multiplication or whatever.

The steps that are used for example in Hadoop or just multithreaded environment.

1. Get input from a source.
2. Divide the input into chunks,the number of chunks should be related to the node count.
3. Send these chunk to each processing node/thread
4. Wait for all threads to complete
5. Gather processed information and show it user after merging

How can I do the same using SLURM or any PBS.

```
 #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 4
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH --time=0-00:15:00     # 30 minutes
#SBATCH --job-name="just_a_test"

what I have to write here ?
```

Please explain this or give a good article to read about, because I haven't found any. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to do this is to use pbsdsh:

```
pbsdsh hostname
```

will make the hostname command execute once for each execution slot (core or thread) in your job. I will also point out that you'll need to translate your #SBATCH to their #PBS equivalents.

The more universal way to do this is through [MPI](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/) implementations.